# JavaScript | How To -1 Second

Tags: javascript

How would I -1 data value every second on a var?

For example a timer is set for -1 every second it will show it decreasing?

Comment: What have you tried? Did Google really show no results at all when you searched for "javascript decrement variable every second"?

Comment: You want to search for "timer" or "clock".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    a--;
    console.log(a);
}, 1000);
```